# What does 'soon' mean in PhD applications?

Tags: phd, application, interview

I had a PhD interview on 8th March. One of the interviewers told me they will let me know the decision 'soon'. I had the impression that the interview did not go bad. It is been more than a week that I haven't heard anything from them. I wanted to ask you is it still soon to get in touch with them? I am asking since there is an exam in the next week and if I'm accepted, I will withdraw from that exam. The university is in central Europe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in writing a polite email similar to your question here, explaining that you have this exam coming up and the outcome of the interview will dictate whether you take it. The best case scenario is they let you know you have been successful; probably they will just give you a date by which they will tell you the outcome. I think you have nothing to lose by asking.

Comment: That's a good advice, I'll add that the typical "soon" in central Europe means "in less than two weeks".